# При чтении файла Warning: file_get_contents(files/..): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, .htaccess

Пытаюсь зачитать файлы из папки,пишу следующее

```
  <?php   
   $dir="files";
    $entries = scandir($dir,1);
    $filelist = array();
    foreach($entries as $entry) {
        $filelist[] = $entry;
    }   
    foreach ($filelist as $file) {
        echo $path=$dir."/".$file;
        $text = file_get_contents($path);
    }
```

Получаю
    Warning: file_get_contents(files/..): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\files.php on line 10
 Использую локальный сервер XAMPP ,смотрел папку files там вроде доступ к ней есть, непойму как поправить

Comment: Стоит заменить `/` на DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR и проверять фаил на наличие функцией `file_exists`

Answer (score 1):

Замени

```
$entries = scandir($dir,1);
```

на

```
$entries = array_diff(scandir($dir, 1), array('..', '.'));
```