# Отклонение в доступе к файлам

Tags: php

> file_get_contents: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Изменяла уже  в параметрах безопасности разрешения, меняла владельца на Все изменяла в FileZilla разрешения к файлам перед скачиванием, но ошибка осталась. При создании в той же папке новых текстовых файлов и их изменении, ошибку не выдает, а вот скопированные файлы изменять не хочет

```
$dir = '../kek';
$files1 = scandir($dir);

print_r($files1);

foreach ($files1 as $f){
  $homepage = file_get_contents("..\kek\\$f");

  if ($homepage == ""){
    unlink($f);
  }
}
```

Comment: Неправильно выставили права, не на того пользователя

Comment: поменяла и владельца на "Все" и выставила разрешения для "Все"

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/556514/256824